# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS suddenly logout

Tags: 18.04

I have a problem some times when starting my PC after I  logged in and start working, all of a sudden ubuntu log out and closes every window I 've opened. Do you know what causing this problem?

I run journal command as suggested bellow these are the results:

> Failed to Raise Network interface
>
> ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
>
> ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
>
> dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object propert
>
> dbus: Failed to construct signal
>
> spice-vdagent[3175]: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-
> ports/com.redhat.
>
> io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1
>
> [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed:
> org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible
> causes include: the remote application did
>
> (*)gnome-session-binary[2879]: Unrecoverable failure in required
> component org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.desktop
>
> (*)gnome-session-binary[2879]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is
> dead. Sorry....

I think the last two are causing the problem but what maybe be the reason?

Comment: When you log in again, look at the last 10 minutes of the logs with `journalctl --since="$(date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%D' --date='now - 10 minutes')"`

Comment: fail to parse timestamp I tried for different minutes back 10,30,60

Comment: Which display driver are you using. Is it Nouveau.

Comment: @Vijay No I am using nvidia. and if you run nvidia-smi the version is 418.39

Comment: My typo, sorry. Fixed version: `journalctl --since="$(date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' --date='now - 10 minutes')" ` (change `%D` to `%S`)